# How to make a 3d beam effect with XNA 4.0?

Tags: 3d, xna-4.0, graphic-effects

Do you know any demo or tutorial to learn to make a 3D Beam effect?

I have learn to make a 2D laser by simply using a texture and moving it thru screen.
But I am a little bit lost while trying to do it in 3D.

After googling I've found several examples, but they are old, not working or made for an older version of XNA.

As a visual hint, what I want to achieve is some 3d beam effect similar to this photo:

[image: Example]

Comment: moving from old version of XNA to new is very easy, try to add to you question links with examples that you have found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if is exactly this what you are looking for !!

http://www.catalinzima.com/samples/lightning-sample/ (in the end of the comments there is a link for a Xna 4.0 version)
if you adjust the provided setting, you will be able to create an effect similar to the one you posted.

Comment: Can you provide more info than just a link? In case the linked site goes down the answer is lost as well.